# Почему функция не возвращает массив чисел. В чем ошибка?

Tags: c++, c, массивы, строки, cs50

Задана переменная n = strlen(text);(для указания длинны массива который нужно заполнить, и для понимания до каких пор продолжать цикл i < n)
Сам массив index[n];
Функция которая принимает строку раскладывает ее на отдельные элементы[i], проверяет каждый text[i] с помощью функции isalpha на то буква ли это, если ответ true с помощью функций islower и isupper проверяет на регистр. Если символ не явлеяется буквой тогда index[i] остается без изменений(index[i] = text[i];).Соотвественно в зависимости от регистра делает вычесления и полученный результат записывает в массив целых чисел index (index[i] = text[i] - 'a';).
Возвращает записанный  массив: return index[n];
Все компилируется но возвращает 0;
Прообовал менять типы данных в возварщаемого массива, возвращать не массив а строку(хотя идея конечно сомнительная). В общем не имею ни малейшего понятия в чем кроется ошибка.
Судя из моей логики эта функция долджна возвращать массив целых чисел. Спасибо за внимание.

```
int alphabetical(string text)
{


    int n = strlen(text);
    int index[n];

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(text[i]))
        {
             if(islower(text[i]))
             {
                 index[i] = text[i] - 'a';
             }
             else if(isupper(text[i]))
             {
                 index[i] = text[i] - 'A';
             }
        }
        else
        {
            index[i] = text[i];
        }
    }
    return index[n];
}
```

Comment: Единственная мысль как заставить это работать это переписать функцию так что бы она работала с каждым символом в отдельности его и возвращала. Но может ли работать она в таком виде?

Comment: чтобы что-то возвращать плавающего размера нужно выделить память. Изучайте команду `new`.

Comment: *"Судя из моей логики эта функция долджна возвращать массив целых чисел. "* - поcмотрите внимательно на тип возвращаемого значение в объявлении функции `int alphabetical`

Comment: Функции не могут возвращать массивы. Только указатели. Если не хотите пока изучать их, то вынесите действия `int n = strlen(text); int index[n];` в вызывающий код и модифицируйте свою функцию -- **`void alphabetical(string text, int n, int index[]) { ... }`** (а также, поправьте в ней цикл for -- `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)` ( i <= n -- это у вас сейчас ошибка))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Возвращает записанный массив: `return index[n];`* — увы, это возврат конкретного элемента. К тому же выходящего за границы массива :)

И, кстати, `for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)` — тут вы тоже выходите за рамки массива. Возвращайте или указатель на динамический массив в памяти (только его надо не забыть потом удалить), либо некоторый объект класса, в котором будет содержаться массив.

Кстати, можно вернуть просто `string` — если текст английский, смещения будут вполне помещаться в `char`, вот вам и нужный массив...

Например, строку можно вернуть вот так:

```
string alphabetical(string text)
{
    for(char&c: text)
        if(isalpha(c))
             if(islower(c)) c -= 'a';
             else if(isupper(c)) c-= 'A';
    return text;
}
```

**Update**

```
string alphabetical(string text)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < text.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(isalpha(text[i]))
            if(islower(text[i])) text[i] -= 'a';
            else if(isupper(text[i])) text[i]-= 'A';
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Такая запись как у вас мне пока не совсем ясна, хотя в принципе все более менее  кроме строки for(char&c: text). На сколько я могу судить это упрощенная запись условий цикла. Могу предположить  что цикл будет работать пока (возможно пока & есть из чего вычеслять)  ... вот тут не яснo. Нагуглил что & это побитовый оператор а дальше темный лес. Обьясните пожалуйста этот на данный момент загадачный для меня синтаксис.

Comment: Ну, раз у вас `&` — побитовое И, а не ссылка, см. вторую версию кода в ответе...